# Destructure a JsonObject to a GraphQL Type on Return

Tags: java, json, scala, graphql, vert.x

Vertx is a big fan of json being a first class citizen, and I'm a big fan of it as well. I have jsonb columns stored in postgres as my primary data storage mechanism. Kind of like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE game (
    id varchar(16) not null default next_id() primary key,
    data jsonb not null
);
```

and I retrieve the data, work on the json object, and return it to the browser. Works great.

I'm trying to use GraphQL as well, though, but it seems that I can't convert a json object into the graphql type. e.g. i have this data stored in the db:

```
{"name": "dominion", "createdBy": "Donald X. Vaccarino", "id": 233}
```

and this is the graphql type:

```scala
type Game {
    id: Long,
    name: String,
    createdBy: String,
    createdAt: DateTime,
    deletedAt: DateTime
}
```

and this graphql query returns a list of empty items because the jsonObject (game) within the jsonArray doesn't get desctructured into the `Game` type:

```scala
type Query {
    allGames(secureOnly: Boolean = false): [Game]
}
```

but the list of games does show up if i use json for the query result type:

```scala
type Query {
    allGames(secureOnly: Boolean = false): [JSON]
}
```

The problem with this, though, is that there is now no type information in the graphql schema. There's no way to let the client know what properties are in the `JSON` object

My data fetcher has this type:

```scala
DataFetcher[CompletionStage[JsonArray]]
```

Any thoughts on how I can return a json in code and have the graphql response return the game type?

Comment: @andrewjames, thank you for catching that. I was changing some of the code around from its original form and forgot to change that place as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default GraphQL data fetcher is `PropertyDataFetcher`.

If you want to support Vert.x `JsonObject` and `JsonArray`, you must configure GraphQL-Java to use VertxPropertyDataFetcher instead:

```
RuntimeWiring.Builder builder = RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring();
builder.wiringFactory(new WiringFactory() {
  @Override
  public DataFetcher<Object> getDefaultDataFetcher(FieldWiringEnvironment environment) {
    return VertxPropertyDataFetcher.create(environment.getFieldDefinition().getName());
  }
});
```